# Fivestar 'Rate' Graphics not showing correctly

Tags: rating

I'm using Fivestar 'rate' across 3 separate web projects. It works fine on 2, but as shown in the graphic link below, has issues on one. I've tried to no avail to figure out what the issue is and compared all other modules across the other installs but I can't see what is causing it. I'm using the latest version of Fivestar, checked file permissions etc, etc. The Fivestar rating is as a field within a Content Node Panel Page.

[image]

Of course the images should just show Five Stars and not a "Give it x/5" five line-wide list with rating (4/05 etc) on it.

Has anyone else had this issue and how did you fix it. Any other suggestions welcome.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Check the JS console, there's probably an error stopping the fivestar JS from running

Comment: Ok, Cheers Clive (-:

Comment: If you found where the issue was, post it as an answer and post it as a solution. That will help others that run into the same issue.